# I dont know why the performClick() method not called

Tags: android, view

I am writing a button implementing Checkable interface. and I override the method: performClick, but it is not called. As per mentioned in the doc:

> Description copied from class: android.view.View 
>   Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

I think it should be called automatically by system when I click the button on the screen. but nothing happens. Or I have to call it for myself?

I have below code:

```
public class MyButton extends Button implements Checkable {

private static final String TAG = "MyButton";
private boolean mChecked;
private boolean mBroadcasting;

private OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeListener;
private OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener;

private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
        android.R.attr.state_checked
};

public MyButton(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Log.i(TAG, "begin to paint lines");
    Paint paint = getPaint();

    paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, this.getWidth(), 0, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, this.getHeight(), paint);
    canvas.drawLine(this.getWidth(), 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, this.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), paint);
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
    event.setClassName(MyButton.class.getName());
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
    info.setClassName(MyButton.class.getName());
}



@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    toggle();
    Log.i(TAG, "the view was clicked");
    return super.performClick();
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    if (mChecked != checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();

        // Avoid infinite recursions if setChecked() is called from a listener
        if (mBroadcasting) {
            return;
        }

        mBroadcasting = true;
        if (mOnCheckedChangeListener != null) {
            mOnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
        }
        if (mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener != null) {
            mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
        }

        mBroadcasting = false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
    Log.i(TAG, "the view was toggled");
}

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);

    if (isChecked()) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
    }
    return drawableState;
}

public OnCheckedChangeListener getOnCheckedChangeListener() {
    return mOnCheckedChangeListener;
}

public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeListener) {
    this.mOnCheckedChangeListener = mOnCheckedChangeListener;
}

public OnCheckedChangeListener getOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener() {
    return mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener;
}

public void setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener(OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener) {
    this.mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener = mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener;
}

/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the checked state
 * of a compound button changed.
 */
public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    /**
     * Called when the checked state of a compound button has changed.
     *
     * @param buttonView The compound button view whose state has changed.
     * @param isChecked  The new checked state of buttonView.
     */
    void onCheckedChanged(MyButton buttonView, boolean isChecked);
}
```

}

MyButton in layout:

```
<com.example.demo.view.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/mybtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/checkable_button"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_text"
    android:text="checkable" />
```

Thank you in advanced.

**Below the 1st answer is correct .**

*explanation:*

> public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) this one is
>   called. Then it calls MyButton(context, attrs, 0). This is where
>   defStyleAttr is being set to 0, while by default it would be
>   com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use proper constructors:

```
public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}
```

**Edit:**

These are the constructors from the `Button` class:

```
public Button(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle);
}

public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}
```

See if you can find the difference between these and your constructors.

Comment: hey, it really works . but why? I don't find any problem with my constructors.I think using this() it use super() finally.

Comment: @evolever it does, but it calls the super constructor with incorrect arguments.

Comment: which constructor is called for this?

Comment: @evolever I've added the code of the `Button` class constructors, see if you can find the mistake you were making by not calling the super constructors.

Comment: hi, i added the layout in the question. can you explain which constructor is called?

Comment: but actually i comment the 4th constructor in my running code.

Comment: cause i dont use v21 api

Comment: @evolever `public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` this one is called. Then it calls `MyButton(context, attrs, 0)`. This is where defStyleAttr is being set to 0, while by default it would be `com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle`.